# How to enable Log-in page in Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, auth0

I'm using [this tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/) as a base of my app security.

Given tutorial allows user to log-in via `http://localhost:8080/login` using http POST method to send username and password.

Now, I know that Spring-Security comes with built in Log-in mechanism. Is there a simple way to somehow access and enable this build in login page?

[image: Text]

This is how configuration looks like:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            // this disables session creation on Spring Security
     .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}
```

Looking forward for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

This page is created by default if you use spring security. Everything you need is to add 2 dependecies to classpath of your spring boot application:
1. Web
2. Security

I created a link for you: https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.3.0.RELEASE&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=11&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=web,security

If you go by this link and click "Generate" at the bottom of the page - a new empty spring boot project will be downloaded as archive. If you unpack it, build and execute you will see in console output:
[image]

It means spring security is enabled and password is created. You will see default login page by url: http://localhost:8080/

You can use username "user" and password generated by spring in console output for login.

[image]

Your article uses JWT tokens for authorization, but default spring security mechanism relies on sessions. So, this form should be configured another way, like in this article: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login

Comment: I want to keep everything the same as it is in this tutorial - I am using JWT tokens. Now I just wonder if it is possible to somehow use existing (built in) login form for loging in users. Spring boot starter web and security are already included in dependencies.